# AngularJS Directive Object Has "No Method"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am currently moving around code in an AngularJS app and have started to receive an error on a customer directive.  The directive works fine in the original, but is returning the error listed below after I've moved a few things.

I have been working through the code to try and find a reference I missed, a file version that is off, or any other reason why this error is suddenly popping up.  I've unfortunately not found anything.

What might be causing the following error to occur on an AngularJS directive?

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'slider'
   at link (http://localhost:8000/static/modeling/js/directives/slider.js:9:13)
   at k (http://localhost:8000/static/js/angular.min.js:44:444)
   at e (http://localhost:8000/static/js/angular.min.js:40:139)
   at e (http://localhost:8000/static/js/angular.min.js:40:156)
   at e (http://localhost:8000/static/js/angular.min.js:40:156)
   at e (http://localhost:8000/static/js/angular.min.js:40:156)
   at k (http://localhost:8000/static/js/angular.min.js:44:382)
   at e (http://localhost:8000/static/js/angular.min.js:40:139)
   at e (http://localhost:8000/static/js/angular.min.js:40:156)
   at http://localhost:8000/static/js/angular.min.js:39:205 <slider id="slider" scale="scale" class="span2 ng-isolate-scope ng-scope">
```

My directive is defined as follows:

```
myApp.directive('slider', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        scale: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
        console.log(elm);
        elm.slider({  // !! THIS IS LINE 9 (per error message) !!
            min: 1,
            max: 50,
            step: 1,
            value: 30,
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                scope.scale = ui.value;
                scope.$apply();
            }
        })
      }
    }
});
```

An example HTML tag being used is:

```
<slider id="slider" scale="scale" class="span2"></slider>
```

Comment: Looks like you might be forgetting to include jQueryUI in your reconfigured app.

Comment: Thank you!  Please provide in answer form so I may further extoll the solution! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are be forgetting to include jQueryUI in your reconfigured app.

Answer (score 2):

The order of includes are important!
The correct order:

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
...
```